# converting from int to float in C changes value

Tags: c, casting

Hi I'm trying to convert from an `int` to a `float` in C and for some reason the cast changes the value and I'm not sure why. So:

```
fprintf (stderr, "%d,%d\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);
```

produces two different numbers. Note that `rgbValues->green` is an `int`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to say that in your format string. Use:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d,%f\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);
                     ^
```

instead of:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d,%d\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);
                     ^
```

Note the change from `d` to `f` (the circumflex `^` isn't part of the code, just an indicator as to where to look).

Comment: The comment line on top is probably meant to indicate the change to be made. 
`fprintf(stderr, "%d,%f\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);` is what it should be.

Comment: I see the comment -- that doesn't make the code any less wrong.

Comment: @Adam I hope you see that `%f` is meant to be replaced with `%d`. That's why I put `%f` *exactly* above `%d`.

Comment: I'm with Adam, that just looks weird.  It's right, but weird.

Comment: @AraK: Actually you want to say that %d is meant to be replaced with %f... :)

Comment: Of course I see that.  My point is that you should actually spell out what the correct code is, not copy the wrong code and awkwardly indicate the change to be made.

Comment: @Adam I see your point. I though this "one letter" change wouldn't be clear. Thats why I tried to make it clear in the above comment.

Comment: There ya go, that should hopefully make it a bit more obvious to all.

Answer (score 6):

The `%d` format specifier says to `printf`, "take the next 4 bytes off of the stack, interpret them as an integer, and print out that integer."  Since you're actually passing a `float` as a parameter, the bytes of the `float` (which are stored in [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format) are getting misinterpreted as an integer, hence the different values.  (Actually, the `float` is getting converted to a `double` due to argument promotion within variadic functions, and it's the first 4 bytes of that promoted `double` that are getting interpreted as an integer.)

The correct solution is to use one of the `%e`, `%f`, or `%g` format specifiers instead of `%d` when printing out a `float`.  `%e` says, "take the next 8 bytes off the stack, interpret them as a `double`, and print it out using scientific (exponential) notation"  `%f` prints out using a fixed-point format, and `%g` prints out whichever would be shorter of `%e` or `%f`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d,%f\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @[AraK's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628468/converting-from-int-to-float-in-c-changes-value/1628473#1628473) answer, you're casting once to `float`, and then `printf` is interpreting that bit pattern as an `int` in the format specifier string. It's doing *exactly* what you're telling it to do :)

If you want to *only* cast to `float` - do this:

```
// format specifier is %d for int, %f for float
// show the cast value of rgbValues->green as well as its "real" value
fprintf(stderr, "%d,%f\n", rgbValues->green, (float)rgbValues->green);
```

**Edit** - wording based on comments

Comment: It's essential to note, however, that they are different types of casts:  the first cast converts the integer value to a floating point value, but the second *reinterprets the floating point value* as if it were an integer.

Comment: It's not really a double-cast, `printf()` has no idea that your number is a `float`, so it can't cast it back to an `int` (which would do the right thing and print the same number twice).  It's just interpreting the bit pattern you sent it (a floating point number) as an integer (since that's what you told it it was in the format string), and printing garbage.

Comment: @Carl - you're right, that's better wording than how I said it :)